# How to reset background color of a python tkinter button?

Tags: python, tkinter

Simple question, have parsed numerous search results, haven't found a simple answer.  I set a very urgent button to red if something is not found so users click it first.  Once clicked, I want to set the background back to normal like `button.config(bg='')`.  I tried 'grey' but it's not the right color.

What do I set it to?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can ask the button what color it is before you change it. Save the color, and then restore it later:

```
orig_color = the_button.cget("background")
the_button.configure(background="red")
...
the_button.configure(background=orig_color)
```

Answer (score 8):

The default colour for buttons is `SystemButtonFace`. I am not sure how many versions of Windows this spans back to, but it is the default system colour for buttons.

You can find the default colours by using @Bryan Oakley's answer above, and then `print()` it to the console.

Comment: Here's some old effbot [Widget Styling documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112014139id_/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-widget-styling.htm) that lists the names of a bunch of the system default colors for Windows and Macintosh.

Comment: You can use it on Windows as `button.config(bg='SystemButtonFace')`

Answer (score 3):

I use the code:

```
def ToGray(self, to_gray):
    to_gray['bg'], to_gray['fg'] = "SystemButtonFace", "Black"
```

Then you can get the default button or label.

Answer (score 3):

The default background color of tkinter is `#f0f0f0`. Hope this helps ;)