# Python GUI - How to change a button's colour by pressing a keyboard input?

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote a program in Python where i have a GUI which shows 4 buttons (up down left right) and when i press them from my keyboard, they give back a message. What i want is that when i press the button, i want the box field to be coloured in red or something + the message that shows which button is pressed.

```
from tkinter import *


window = Tk()
window.title("Arrow Keys")
window.geometry('820x640')
width = 820
height = 640


myButton1 = Button(window, text="    UP   ", activebackground='red')
myButton1.place(x= 387, y=10)
myButton2 = Button(window, text="DOWN", activebackground='red')
myButton2.place(x= 399, y= 60)
myButton2.pack(pady=60)
myButton3 = Button(window, text=" LEFT ", activebackground='red')
myButton3.place(x= 345, y=35)
myButton4 = Button(window, text="RIGHT", activebackground='red')
myButton4.place(x= 435, y= 35)

def up(event):
    myLabel = Label(window, text="Press UP")
    myLabel.pack()

def down(event):
    myLabel = Label(window, text="Press DOWN")
    myLabel.pack()

def left(event):
    myLabel = Label(window, text="Press LEFT")
    myLabel.pack()

def right(event):
    myLabel = Label(window, text="Press RIGHT")
    myLabel.pack()

window.bind("<Up>", up)
window.bind("<Down>", down)
window.bind("<Left>", left)
window.bind("<Right>", right)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does `myButton1.configure(bg='yellow')` in `up` fit your needs ? cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36093839/how-to-reset-background-color-of-a-python-tkinter-button

Comment: thank you! But i want when i press "the up arrow from my keyboard", the UP button from GUI should light a colour that gives me a visual signal that i pressed it, and when i release the up arrow, the button from GUI should go grey again (disabled)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- define the status label `myLabel` outside callback function
- define a dictionary to link the key name and the corresponding button
- bind `<KeyPress>` and `<KeyRelease>` to corresponding callbacks and update the background color of the corresponding button and the text of `myLabel` inside the callbacks

```py
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Arrow Keys")
window.geometry('820x640')
width = 820
height = 640

myButton1 = Button(window, text="    UP   ", activebackground='red')
myButton1.place(x= 387, y=10)
myButton2 = Button(window, text="DOWN", activebackground='red')
myButton2.place(x= 399, y= 60)
#myButton2.pack(pady=60) ### don't call pack() after using place()
myButton3 = Button(window, text=" LEFT ", activebackground='red')
myButton3.place(x= 345, y=35)
myButton4 = Button(window, text="RIGHT", activebackground='red')
myButton4.place(x= 435, y= 35)

# save the background color or button
btn_bg = myButton1.cget("bg")

myLabel = Label(window)
myLabel.place(x=50, y=50)

keys = {"Up": myButton1, "Down": myButton2, "Left": myButton3, "Right": myButton4}

def on_key_press(event):
    if event.keysym in keys:
        keys[event.keysym].config(bg="red")
        myLabel.config(text=event.keysym)

def on_key_release(event):
    if event.keysym in keys:
        keys[event.keysym].config(bg=btn_bg)
        myLabel.config(text="")

window.bind("<KeyPress>", on_key_press)
window.bind("<KeyRelease>", on_key_release)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to also bind the corresponding `KeyRelease-*` events.
For instance, add to your code:

```
def up(event):
   ...
   myButton1.configure(bg='yellow')

def up_release(event):
   myButton1.configure(bg='grey')

...
window.bind("<KeyRelease-Up>", up_release)
```

See e.g. [TkInter keypress, keyrelease events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27215326/tkinter-keypress-keyrelease-events) for more details, and [How to reset background color of a python tkinter button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36093839/how-to-reset-background-color-of-a-python-tkinter-button) to restore the previous color (instead of grey).